# How to create an auto-incremental column based on two other columns in R Shiny?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, mutate

I work with R Shiny.
My app imports a CSV file and just after I'd like to add a new auto-incremental column called "campagne".

With that new column, the structure of my CSV would be the one. See that "Campagne" is filled depending to "Code" and "Date" columns :

```
Code  Date  Campagne  
A1  05/07  1  
A1  05/07  1  
A1  06/07  2  
A1  08/07  3  
A1  08/07  3  
B1  06/08  1  
B1  06/08  1  
B1  08/08  2  
B1  09/08  3  
B1  10/08  4
```

I tried the following code (with dplyr package) that works very well in R but not in R Shiny. It seems the `group by ()` function makes Shiny crash because without it the column is well created (but incorrectly filled).

```
inFile <- input$importData
data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=T, sep=';', colClasses = c(Code = "character", Code2 = "character"))
data <- data %>%
   group_by(Code) %>% 
   mutate(Campagne = match(Date, unique(Date)))
```

Are there other alternatives to create that auto-incremential column, with dplyr or other packages ?  I must admit I'm completely stuck on that problem..

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing in that code that should make shiny crash, so long as the data meets your expectations (has columns `"Code"` and `"Date"`). I suggest you debug your code mid-shiny by placing `browser()` after the `read.csv(...)` line of code, then examine `Data` to see why it might be causing a problem. (FYI, is there a reason you're using `read.csv(..., sep=";")` instead of `read.csv2(...)`? Not sure it's related.)

Comment: Also, *how* does shiny crash?  Are you sure that the problem isn't that one of your reactives is expecting `data` to exist but it doesn't on initialisation?  Also, is `input$importData` a `fileInput`?  If so, you don't appear to be using it correctly. (See [here](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.7.3/fileinput)).  With a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we might be able to help you more...